# Laravel 5.1 create a product linked to user_id

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, model-view-controller

I'm trying to do a one to many relationship using laravel 5.1 . The problem is that when I create a new product it doesn't belong to any user in my database. I have 2 tables in my database: products and users. One of the rows in my products table is user_id.

```
public function create()
{
    return view('products.create');
}


public function store(Request $request)   
{
    $inputs = $request->all();
    $product = Product::Create($inputs);
    return redirect()->action('ProductController@index');
}
```

This is the code in my ProductController.
And this is code in my model.

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'price',
        'descr',
        'image',
        'sale',
        'user_id'
    ];
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'products';
    public function books(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Books');
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to do this whatever I try. If I've forgotten to add anything above tell me.
Thank you

Comment: I'll explain everything. let me write my answer.

Answer (score 4):

For one to many relationship or any relationship you need to have correct database structure. For example in your case you have two table `products` and `users`

Lets just create migration for your tables `products` and `users`

**Migration**

```
Schema::create('users',function(Blueprint $table){
    $table->increaments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    //and so on ...
});
```

So basically to identify users you've got `users.id` column.

```
Schema::create('products',function(Blueprint $table){
    $table->increaments('id');
    $table->string('product_name');
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    //and so on ...
    
    $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Now you have your `users` table and your `products` table. And there's a relationship between your tables is users can have products.

**Models**

```
class User extends Model {
    public function products(){
        return $this->hasMany('\App\Product'); //Product Model Name
    }
}
```

Now if you want to access `products` which belongs to `users` you'll have to do this in your controller.

```
$user = Users::find(1); //lets say for test we just took firs user
return $user->products()->get();
```

This will give you a clean json of user details and along with the products which is associated with that particular user.

NOTE: In your case you don't have any user_id associated with your product details, in that case it wont work as there should be some relationship.

**For Storing the data into database**

```
public function create()
{
    return view('products.create');
}


public function store(Request $request)   
{

    $inputs = $request->all();

    $product = Product::Create($inputs);

    return redirect()->action('ProductController@index');

}
```

Now you're mass assigning the values into database so `$request->all()` must have `user_id` of the logged user.
So create a hidden field in the form area of `products.create` view.

```
<form action="someaction" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{Auth::user()->id}}"/>
    <input type="text" name="product_name" />
</form>
```

Now your `$request->all()` method will contain key `user_id` and its value form logged in user.

`Auth::user()` gives the information of logged in users;

Alternatively in your controller you can do like this too..

```
    public function store(Request $request)   
    {
 $request->user_id = Auth::user()->id; //assigning user_id value to the current logged in user's id (this has to be before adding the request to the inputs variable so when  you execute ::Create($inputs) it will be there)
        $inputs = $request->all();
       
        $product = Product::Create($inputs);

        return redirect()->action('ProductController@index');

    }
```

Hope this would help. :)

Comment: thanks bro but I couldnt get it to work. What Im trying to do is when I create a product to be automatically assigned to the logged in user. I don't know if we are talking about the same thing here.

Comment: well done  imrealashu but  check the store function! you add request to inputs variable then add Auth::user()->id to request? i think you need to reorder that

Comment: glad i could help. please mark it as accepted too. It will gain me few more reputations also. :)

Comment: Creating a hidden input field, allows people to tamper with the request, creating a product linked to a different user id.